# @font-face Doesn't Work on iOS? Just some fonts don't work?

Tags: html, ios, css, fonts

I'm building a mobile landing page specifically designed for iPhones, and I'd like to use Rockwell as the h1 font on the page. Here's the URL:

[radionowheremusic.com/mobile7.html](http://www.radionowheremusic.com/mobile7.html)

On my phone, the header is clearly devolving to the next font in the stack, Courier New. But it rendered as Rockwell on my laptop in Chrome, Safari, etc.

As far as I can tell, I've set up the html and css for the page and the font to work correctly. Is there something I've missed, though, and is my laptop somehow using locally-installed fonts to render the headline in Rockwell? Or is there something funky about iOS + @font-face?

Thanks!

EDIT: Aha. Turns out it was just a syntax error. Of course. Move along, people, nothing to see here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding custom font to IOS app, you need to add an array in info.plist with key name as "Fonts provided by application". As shown in image[image]

Comment: Thanks, rajath. Turns out it was a simple error on my part. Thanks for your time!